# Unable to use Facebook Places after manually setting Geolocation in Firefox

Tags: facebook, geolocation

I am having a play with Facebook Places but don't want to publish my current location for privacy reasons. I therefore changed the geo.wifi.uri in the about:config in Firefox to point to a file containing JSON of my location with the lat and long. This works great and if I test by using Google Maps or the Mozilla Geolocation test I get the location I have specified. However, if I 'Check in' via Facebook (touch.facebook.com) in Firefox I can see the location on the little Bing map but get the following error

***We couldn't determine the coordinates of this location. Check if your latitude and longitude are in range, and verify the format of the location.\n***

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have wired up Google Latitude to Firefox geolocation. This lets you manually update your location in Google Latitude with a single mouse click, instead of looking up your latitude and longitude yourself and typing it into a local file or URI. My article on the subject is [Make Firefox Take Geolocation From Google Latitude](http://metaed.blogspot.com/2010/11/make-firefox-take-geolocation-from.html).

I am not normally a Facebook Places user, but I browsed over to touch.facebook.com and clicked Places, and was presented with the usual permission prompt and then a list of nearby places. So the problem does not seem to be in Facebook or in Firefox. Without looking at your JSON I could not guess why it's not working.

Cheers, MetaEd